# Using Ruby Hash instead of Rails ActiveRecord in Coffeescript / Morris.JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, raphael, morris.js

I'm following the [Railscast #223](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts-graphs-revised) that introduced [Morris.JS](http://oesmith.github.com/morris.js/).

I generate a data set called `@orders_yearly` in my controller and in my view I have the following to try and render the graph:

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", id: "orders_chart", data: {orders: @orders_yearly} %>
```

Calling `@orders_yearly.inspect` shows it's just a simple hash:

```
{2009=>1000, 2010=>2000, 2011=>4000, 2012=>100000}
```

I'll need to modify the values for `xkey` and `ykeys` in coffeescript to work, but I'm not sure how to make it work with my data set:

```
jQuery ->
  Morris.Line
    element: 'orders_chart'
    data: $('#orders_chart').data('orders')
    xkey: 'purchased_at' # <------------------ replace with what?
    ykeys: ['price'] # <---------------------- replace with what?
    labels: ['Price']
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Morris.JS examples here](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/#examples) I suppose you have to change your data hash a little bit.

```
{'purchased_at' => 2009, 'value' =>1000}
{'purchased_at' => 2010, 'value' =>2000}
...
```

Then in Coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  Morris.Line
    element: 'orders_chart'
    data: $('#orders_chart').data('orders')
    xkey: 'purchased_at'
    ykeys: ['value']
    labels: ['Price']
```